# How to know if locally installed programs (like Re Image) are malware

Tags: antivirus, scan, web-of-trust

Not sure where to ask this question but figured I'd ask it here, at least in a generic way. I installed a program called Re Image as I red it helps with system instability problems. However, I then found on google several sources that claim it's malware.

Are there any ways to tell if a program is stealing your data or intending to do damage? Are there communities, like the Web of Trust, that verify the safeness of local programs? There's certainly no shortage of antivirus making false positives (and for what it's worth, windows defender did not detect Re Image as a threat, but sites [like this](https://malwaretips.com/blogs/remove-reimage-repair-ads/) claim that it is).

Does anyone know if Re Image is a threat?

Comment: In this case I think they've classified "ill-behaved adware" as "malware".  And that may depend on if your install package delivered an adware browser plugin without your consent.  Regarding your overall question, there is no authority or community that definitively blesses goodware or identifies malware (VirusTotal comes close.)  And there probably can't be; malware authors would abuse it as a testing ground to prove their software isn't rejected as badware.

Answer (score 2):

The most reliable check in my opinion is [VirusTotal](https://www.virustotal.com/), the online scanner bought by Google.
If the main executable is not too big, upload it there and have it scanned by >50 virus scanners.

Comment: PS: the name does not matter that much unless you compare the actual file to the hash of a trusted source. I could name my virus iexplore.exe and people would tell you it's only dangerous because it's developed by microsoft.